# Added UIScrollView and UIImageView in storyboard - the image is squished and does not scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, scrollview

In Xcode 5.0.2 I have created [a universal app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/Scroll) and dragged a `UIScrollView` and an `UIImageView` into the iPhone and iPad storyboards (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I332.png)):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Then I am trying to load the images `board.png` (copyright Wikipedia Commons, Denelson83) by the following code in [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/Scroll/Scroll/ViewController.m):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"board"];
    NSLog(@"%s: img=%@ (%f x %f)", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
          img, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    _imageView.image = img;
    _scrollView.contentSize = img.size;
}
```

However the result is squished and the image can't be scrolled:

```
-[ViewController viewDidLoad]: img=<UIImage: 0x10912d770> (1000.000000 x 961.500000)
```

[image: app screenshot]

Any advice please? I suspect the image is cut off at the bottom, because I run the 3.5-inch iPhone simulator? How to fix this too?

**UPDATE:**

I am trying to add four 0-constraints to the scroll view, so that it takes the whole screen, but when I rotate the simulator with Cmd-Arrow - the scroll view doesn't resize (here [fullscreen of Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL5vm.png)):

[image: constraints screenshot]

[image: rotated app]

**UPDATE 2:**

When I change the `UIImageView` "view mode" to "Top Left" in Xcode storyboard and the source code to the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"board"];
    _imageView.image = img;
    _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    _scrollView.contentSize = img.size;
}
```

then I get the following result, which can not be scrolled:

[image: app screenshot]

and can not be rotated either (does not fill the screen):

[image: rotated app]

Comment: Have you tried different content modes like "imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;"? Also what are your uiimageview bounds?

Comment: 1. Try to disable 'auto resize subviews' property of the scroll view.

Comment: 2. Try to disable autolayout OR make your changes after or inside - viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Disabling *Autoresize Subviews* does not help unfortunately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that the Storyboard image view already has its size set from the storyboard, and you never resize anything after you have loaded your image in your code. So, this is off the top of my head, but try:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"board"];
_imageView.image = image;
_imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);


- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    _scrollView.contentSize = _imageView.bounds.size;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `_imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height); _scrollView.contentSize = img.size;` makes no difference.

Comment: Please try the above again. I updated the comment to set the contentSize later, which worked for me.